# SMTP on a different port?

Tags: email, server, xampp, isp

I would like to be able to run a SMTP server on port 25, but my ISP blocks it. Is there a way to use a different. I'm running XAMPP Mercury.

Answer (score 1):

My ISP optimum online blocks port 25 and port 80 for regular users. They claim lots of viruses and malware are spread on these ports. Spreading propaganda IMO since 99% of websites run on port 80. Well I upgraded to Boost which lets me use those ports.

Here are two discussions on Mercury and ISP's blocking port 25

http://community.pmail.com/forums/thread/23073.aspx

http://community.pmail.com/forums/thread/7734.aspx